# React native rerenders whole component on modal open/close

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-modal

### My problem

I render a list of simple items (numbers or strings) using `Array.map` method. I use `Modal` to add/update items. However, every opening or closing of the modal makes `react` rerender the whole array, even if the array remains unmodified. I feel this is an expected behavior.

### Questions

1. Is it possible not to rerender the whole component when opening or closing the modal?
2. What is the common way to add/update new items in array without rerendering the entire list?

Thanks, guys

### Minimal code example

```js
/* Console output:
 * ---------------
 * ROOT: render component
 * -> ITEM: render 1
 * -> ITEM: render 2
 * -> ITEM: render 3 (not in map)
 * ROOT: open modal
 * ROOT: render component
 * -> ITEM: render 1
 * -> ITEM: render 2
 * -> ITEM: render 3 (not in map)
 * MODAL: close Modal
 * ROOT: render component
 * -> ITEM: render 1
 * -> ITEM: render 2
 * -> ITEM: render 3 (not in map)
*/
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Modal, Pressable, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const items = [1, 2];

const Item = ({el}) => {
  console.log(`-> ITEM: render ${el}`);
  return <Text>Item: {el}</Text>;
};

const Testing = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const openModal = () => {
    console.log('ROOT: open modal');
    setVisible(true);
  };

  console.log("ROOT: render component");

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>

      {/* Render simple list */}
      <Text style={styles.header}>All items:</Text>
      {items.map(el => (
        <Item el={el} key={el} />
      ))}
      <Item el={'3 (not in map)'} />

      {/* Button to open modal */}
      <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={openModal}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Tap me to open modal</Text>
      </Pressable>

      {/*The Modal*/}
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={visible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          console.log('MODAL: close Modal');
          setVisible(false);
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>No content here...</Text>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#0aa',
    marginVertical: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default Testing;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What I've learned today

Once we create a component, `React` is tracking its state and performs rerendering if the state changes. Rerendering includes all the children of the component. Thus, I can answer my questions.

#### Answer to question 1

Yes. We need `visible` is not in the *state* of the component that we wouldn't like to rerender. To achieve this, the Modal should be implemented separately from our component that turns into the parent of Modal.

At the same time, we want that parent can make set Modal visible. It is here that a new-for-me react hook comes into a play: `useImperativeHandle`.

The workflow is as follows. The parent forwards a reference `ref` to Modal using a `forwardRef` function that wrapps the Modal component. Then, Modal declares `ref` as a handler that can be used by parent. This declaration and available porperties are provided via `useImperativeHandler` hook. That's it.

Note, however, that imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases, as [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) state.

Below is the code snippet as a memento for me. No rerender on Modal open/close at this time!

```js
/* Console output:
 * ---------------
 * ROOT: render component
 * -> ITEM: render 1
 * -> ITEM: render 2
 * -> ITEM: render 3 (not in map)
 * ROOT: open modal
 * MODAL: openMe called from parent component via ref
 * MODAL: close Modal
 */

//
// Modal component
//
const _MyModal = (props, ref) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const openMe = () => {
    console.log('MODAL: openMe called from parent component via ref');
    setVisible(true);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({publicHandler: openMe}}), [openMe]));

  return (<Modal>...</Modal>);
};

const MyModal = forwardRef(_MyModal);

//
// Testing component
//
const Testing = () => {
  const modalRef = useRef(null);

  const openModal = () => {
    console.log('ROOT: open modal');
    modalRef.current.publicHandler();
  };
  
  // Rest of code without <Modal> tag
}
```

#### Answer to question 1 using `redux`

If you use `redux`, there is no need in `useImperativeHandle` hook. Just connect Modal component to `store` to share `visible` and action creator `actSetVisible`, while connect the parent component to share only this action creator `actSetVisible`. Everything works similarly as illustrated above.

However, if you do want to use `useImperativeHandle`, you should point `redux` to the fact that you're forwarding a reference, when connecting Modal to store:

```js
const MyModal = connect(mapS2P, mapD2P, null, {forwardRef: true}))(forwardRef(_MyModal));
```

#### Answer to question 2

The suggestions from above showed how to get rid of excessive rerendering when modal opens or closes. My second question implied that I do something newbily wrong in react because I'm really a newby here. Therefore, in my humble opinion, using Modals is a good way to add elements to lists. In my case, it was an array of composed components rather than an array of simple strings, and rerendering was a critical issue.

### Afterword

Live a century, learn a century, and you'll die a fool. Hope, this will help to anyone.

Comment: After trying every possible solution under the sun (changing functional to class component, using redux, putting the modal above at the root-component, useCallback,  React.memo etc.) to not let the showing of my Chakra-Modal rerender its parent component, your forwardRef-Method finally was the holy grail. What seems to be missing is `<Modal ref={ref}>...</Modal>` and `<MyModal ref={modalRef} />`. Without it it doesn't work for me. Can't say I really understood the solution, but we'll anyway port our project to Vue3, hopefully.

Comment: Hi! Can you please share full code, I am not sure where to put the references :/

Comment: Unfortunately, most framework tutorials put the Modal inline just to simplify the code and focus on teaching how to use their modal. Any seasoned React engineer would instantly see the problem with that approach. In most cases, the extra render wouldn't matter, but when it does, it becomes a headache. Going straight to a state-manager path is a good initial investment.  It's also a more flexible design, where the modal can be controlled outside of React (i.e. from javascript logic, from console, from devtools, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

The reason it re-renders is because you are updating state (setVisible).

You can useRef.

useState is directly tied with a components lifecycle; useRef is not, meaning you can change it and it won't trigger a re-render.

Example:

```js
       const visible = useRef()

       //your code

       useEffect(() => {
         visible.current = false  //initiate to false  or true 
         depending on what you need.
       }, [])

      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={visible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          console.log('MODAL: close Modal');
          visible.current = !visible.current //will toggle between true and false
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>No content here...</Text>
     </Modal>
```

Comment: What way do you make the Modal open using useRef? `react` won't rerender anything when you change `visible`

Comment: Editing my answer

Comment: I succeeded with `useImperativeHandle` hook. Please, see the answer above. Anyway, thank you to dive into the subject!

Comment: ref don't cause a update. misuse.